# Unity 2D | How To Make A Character Respawn?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unityscript

I'm using Unity 2D, not 3D, and I'm wondering why my current script won't work. It's not destroying the object and respawning it. Take in mind I'm using unity 2D and 2D physics.
Can anyone help?

```
#pragma strict
var Player : GameObject;
var spawnPoint : Transform;
function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider){
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
    var P : GameObject = Instantiate(Player, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had this problem myself,

Fix:
function OnTriggerEnter2D(otherObject: Collider2D) {

The 2D and 3D commands are different. Really annoying.

Answer (score -1):

What is Player set to? It should be public if you want to set it in the editor.

Is OnTriggerEnter being called at all? Is the spawnPoint visible to the camera?

Also note this code is the same for 2D and 3D.